Enumeration of permutations with prescribed numbers of fixed points and excedance/deficiency statistics
Consider the following refinement of permutation statistics. For $π ∈ S_n$, let:

$\mathrm{fix}(π) = |\{i : π(i) = i\}|$ (number of fixed points)
$\mathrm{exc}(π) = |\{i : π(i) > i\}|$ (number of excedances)
$\mathrm{def}(π) = |\{i : π(i) < i\}|$ (number of deficiencies)

Let $P(n,t,b,c)$ be the number of permutations $π ∈ S_n$ such that
$\mathrm{fix}(π) = t$, $\mathrm{exc}(π) = b$, $\mathrm{def}(π) = c$.

Are there known results about the generating function:
$\sum_n P(n,t,b,c)x^ty^bz^c/n!$

This seems related to both rencontres numbers and Eulerian numbers. Are there known connections between these statistics in the literature?

The exponential generating function for rencontres numbers is well-known. Has this refinement by excedance/deficiency been studied?



The answer is
$$
\sum_n P(n,t,b,c)x^ty^bz^c/n!=e^x\frac{y-z}{ye^z-ze^y}.
$$
Proof sketch: $P(n,t,b,c)$ is the number of pairs $(S,\delta)$ where $S$ is a subset of cardinality $n-t$ in $\{1,...,n\}$ and $\delta$ is a derangement of $S$ with exactly $b$ excedances. Numbers of derangements with given number of excedances are A046739 in OEIS, their generating function is cited as $(1-t)\frac{e^{-tz}}{1 - te^{(1-t)z}}$. Combining these into a single generating function is more or less straightforward.

How would you use this generating function in practice and would this be computationally feasible for larger values of n?

@PeterThomas On that OEIS page there are some recurrences that can be used for computations, corresponding to the two variable generating function (without $e^x$). Three variable case is easily deduced from that.

To be more specific,$$P(n,t,b,c)=\binom ntP(n-t,0,b,c),$$and $P(n-t,0,b,c)$ is the number of derangements of $n-t$ with $b$ excedences (note that $c=n-t-b$), given in A046739 by a recurrence.
